# Breakpoints in the argument-passing scheme of OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml, ocaml-core

Today, I was going through the source code of [Jane Street](https://www.janestreet.com/)'s `Core_kernel` module and I [came across](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/lib/fn.ml#L23-L26) the `compose` function:

```ml
(* The typical use case for these functions is to pass in functional arguments
   and get functions as a result. For this reason, we tell the compiler where
   to insert breakpoints in the argument-passing scheme. *)
let compose f g = (); fun x -> f (g x)
```

I would have defined the `compose` function as:

```ml
let compose f g x = f (g x)
```

The reason they give for defining `compose` the way they did is “because `compose` is a function which takes functions `f` and `g` as arguments and returns the function `fun x -> f (g x)` as a result, they defined `compose` the way they did to tell the compiler to insert a breakpoint after `f` and `g` but before `x` in the argument-passing scheme.”

So I have two questions:

1. Why do we need breakpoints in the argument-passing scheme?
2. What difference would it make if we defined `compose` the normal way?

Coming from Haskell, this convention doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: A similar thing occurs in Haskell when influencing the inliner. The following map definition is better optimized than a more naive one: `map f = go where { go [] = []; go (a : as) = f a : go as }`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson That's only useful because `map` is recursive. Hence, `go as` is more efficient than `map f as`. I don't see how the same concept would apply to `compose` considering that it is not recursive.

Comment: There are non-recursive instances, too. My point is that the inliner only runs when all of the variables in your definition are filled and thus behaves differently between `f x = \y -> ...` and `f x y = ...` despite them being semantically identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an efficiency hack to avoid the cost of a partial application in the expected use case indicated in the comment.

OCaml compiles curried functions into fixed-arity constructs, using a closure to partially apply them where necessary. This means that calls of that arity are efficient - there's no closure construction, just a function call.

There *will* be a closure construction within `compose` for `fun x -> f (g x)`, but this will be more efficient than the partial application. Closures generated by partial application go through a wrapper `caml_curryN` which exists to ensure that effects occur at the correct time (if that closure is itself partially applied).

The fixed arity that the compiler chooses is based on a simple syntactic analysis - essentially, how many arguments are taken in a row without anything in between. The Jane St. programmers have used this to select the arity that they desire by injecting `()` "in between" arguments.

In short, `let compose f g x = f (g x)` is a less desirable definition because it would result in the common two-argument case of `compose f g` being a more expensive partial application.

Semantically, of course, there is no difference at all.

Comment: Wouldn't a closure be built to return `fun x -> f (g x)` anyway? Would building this closure be cheaper wrt building the one associated to partial application? I can't see an obvious reason for that.

Comment: The closures built by partial application involve an additional indirection - they go through `caml_curryN` (which is necessary for the correct evaluation order) rather than straight to the code.

Comment: Does the compiler not treat `let compose f g = fun x -> f (g x)` and `let compose f g x = f (g x)` differently? I wouldn't have thought to interject a `()`.

Comment: No, those are handled the same. `let f x y = ...` is just sugar for `let f = fun x -> fun y -> ...`: when expanded, the two are identical.

Comment: Gotcha. In Haskell they're treated slightly differently with regard to the inliner. It makes a lot of sense to use the `(); E` trick in OCaml too, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that compilation of partial application has improved in OCaml, and this performance hack is no longer necessary.